# Integrating Solr with Stanford NER

Tags: solr, lucene, stanford-nlp

I am trying to integrate Solr/Lucene with Stanford NER.

The site [http://www.searchbox.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-in-solr/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327221947/http://www.searchbox.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-in-solr/) which specified the steps for this is not available anymore.

My question is can someone give me a idea on how to integrate solr/Lucene with stanford NER. It would be great if you have a copy of the steps provided in the searchbox url.

Comment: The site appears to be back up now? Are there additional questions beyond the site?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the instruction in the site to integrate with NER.

Comment: @dhivyaprp Could you post those details here. The link is down again and for good this time it seems, cause the domain is up for sale.

Comment: You know there is web.archive.org? changed the link to the archived version.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20140327221947/http://www.searchbox.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-in-solr/